# Best way to frequently ping some hardware on the network c++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt4, communication

I have a custom made hardware pannel that I need to connect to.

Using QAbstractSocket class, I managed to connect to it and communicate with it.

But the issue is that if I unplug the ethernet cable after the connected state is reached, no update is made to the state.

So i need a way to "ping" it every X seconds to make sure the connection is not lost.

What would be the best way to do so?

- For example, a 2nd thread created once it's connected that will frenquently "ping" the device?

This question is not related to the ping part but to the every X seconds part.

Comment: Did you try to use QTcpSocket?

Comment: Yes, i'm currently working with it.
It is quite easy to use.
I now only need a way to often ping the device to be sure it's still connected. Any advice?

Comment: does your device protocol has ping/pong functionality? What kind of device it is? Is it your own server?

Comment: It's a custom hardware pannel. I used the word ping but that's not exactly right.
This pannel has a poll command i can send and wait for the reply. The only thing is that, if the connection is lost (for example, ethernet cable unplugged, the socket state is not updated. That's why i need a way to "poll" the pannel every X seconds to make sure it's still connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that's the best way but here is what I used.

[QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtimer.html#singleShot-prop) is your fiend in this situation. You don't need to get a different thread for this as it is asynchronous (Qt documentation strongly advises not to use threads in this case [here for example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/thread-basics.html))

I used QTimer to be able to trigger a specific method every interval of time. (you can set the QTimer as singleshot)

I used another QTimer, to wait for the reply, once the first timed out.

By using the signal/slots etc... It was really easy to do.